# Converting a number value in a field to a word

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that I'm building and need to convert a number to a word.

The field is titled Type and the values are 1 or 2. I need to convert the 1 to display as Problem and the 2 to display as Resolution.

How would i go about doing this. I built this as an expression in SQL data tools, but we are going in a different direction and need to add it to the query instead and display the report another way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you have a second table with your ID/Name combination as a lookup and do a  **JOIN**.

That way, as new types come in, you only have to change the name, and not the code.

Although, the syntax would be

```
CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN 'Problem' 
     WHEN Type = 2 THEN 'Resolution' END
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but there will not be any new types just the two i listed. So i typed [Type] CASE WHEN Type = 1 Then 'Problem' When Type = 2 Then 'Resolution' End and its throwing a Syntax error

Comment: well...i added the case stmt

Comment: I saw that after i typed my comment. Thank you! It worked.

Comment: thanks...if it works...please "accept" the answer on screen...cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try below option, it will work with 2 types only (as in question):

```
Declare @Type int = 1

select 
case @Type when 1 then 'Problem'
    else 'Resolution' 
    end as Result

set @Type = 2
select 
case @Type when 1 then 'Problem'
    else 'Resolution' 
end as Result
```

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially built the first portion of a normalized database, you've just haven't completed the second portion. The numbers: 1 and 2, can be foreign keys to a second data table that links to the second table's unique auto-incremented ID field:

```
+-------+    +----+-------------+
|  Type |    | ID | Description |
+-------+    +----+-------------+
|   1   |    | 1  |   Problem   |
|   2   |    | 2  |  Resolution |
|   2   |    +----+-------------+
|   1   |
+-------+
```

Which this schema, you can then query the data like such:

```
SELECT `table2`.`description`
FROM   `table2`
       INNER JOIN `table1`
               ON `table1`.`type` = `table2`.`id`
WHERE  `table1`.`type` = 1
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f8b2/3/0)

What this does is it allows you to add more IDs and Descriptions to your second data table without having to rewrite a bunch of code.